# Grouping of rows having same elements in a column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

`df` is a dataframe in which I need to group together the rows having identical elements in the `Name` column. Finally the duplicated elements in the `Name` column are to be removed.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A","","","B","","","A","","","B","",""),
                 Test = c("test1","test2","test3","test1","test2","test3",
                       "test1.1","test2.1","test3.1","test1.1","test2.1","test3.1"))
```

Desired output:

```
> df
   Name    Test
1     A   test1
2         test2
3         test3
4       test1.1
5       test2.1
6       test3.1
7     B   test1
8         test2
9         test3
10      test1.1
11      test2.1
12      test3.1
```

Comment: What's the reason for this, like a table that's being published somewhere? If so, `kableExtra` has functions for formatting tables like this, but that's intended for Latex or HTML documents. Otherwise it seems like a bad idea from a data management perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following with `tidyverse`. Replace empty character values with `NA` and `fill` down with the `Name` value. Then, sort by `Name`. Finally, keep only the first `Name` in a group.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Name = na_if(Name, "")) %>%
  fill(Name, .direction = "down") %>%
  arrange(match(Name, unique(df$Name))) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Name = ifelse(row_number() == 1, Name, ""))
```

**Output**

```
   Name  Test   
   <chr> <chr>  
 1 "A"   test1  
 2 ""    test2  
 3 ""    test3  
 4 ""    test1.1
 5 ""    test2.1
 6 ""    test3.1
 7 "B"   test1  
 8 ""    test2  
 9 ""    test3  
10 ""    test1.1
11 ""    test2.1
12 ""    test3.1
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. I was wondering if there is a way to keep the order of the elements in the 'Name' column intact. Your solution sorts the elements in the 'Name' column in alphabetical order. In case there is "Z" in place of "A" and "Y" in place of "B", I would like it in the same order i.e. Z on top and Y below.

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury See edited answer. You can change the `arrange` to sort by the original order of `Name`. See if this gives you the desired behavior.

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `na.locf` and `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
  arrange(na.locf(na_if(Name, ""))) %>%
  mutate(Name = replace(Name, duplicated(Name) & Name != "", ""))
```

-output

```
  Name    Test
1     A   test1
2         test2
3         test3
4       test1.1
5       test2.1
6       test3.1
7     B   test1
8         test2
9         test3
10      test1.1
11      test2.1
12      test3.1
```